# not disaplying validation error when i am using preRenderView

Tags: jsf-2

i have page manageUsers. all users will show on primefaces datatable.

for editing user i putted one link name is edit. so when i click on edit it will take id of

user and go to edit page. on edit page i used

`<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{editUserBean.init}"/>.`

so init() method will get request parameter.

my problem is i putted validation on editUser page. when i am submitting form without any

value then it is not displayaing any message error message. and it is doing work without any

value. and on page there is two forms. one form has preRenderView tag and other form has

editable data with validation.

`
public void init() throws Exception
    {

```
    Object o1=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");


    if(o1==null ||(editNews=Facade.othfac().getTVecNewsFindAllValidTill(o1.toString(),Integer.valueOf(o2.toString())))==null)
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/HeWebEV/admin/ManageUsrs.jsf");
    }
    else
    {
        setEditNews(Facade.othfac().getTVecNewsFindAllValidTill(o1.toString(),Integer.valueOf(o2.toString())));
    }

}

public void updateNewsAction() throws Exception
{
    log.info("in UpdateUserAction__");
    save to database.

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/HeWebEV/admin/ManageUser.jsf");
}`
```

it is not calling update action but it is calling init() without parameter so it is

redirecting to other page.

It is working when i am removing preRenderView tag and using Constructor instead of init().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bean must be `@ViewScoped` and the `init()` method should do its job during initial request only, not on postbacks.

```
public void init() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        // Do the job here.
    }
}
```

Comment: problem Solved. you are greate man. thank you Balus C. i really like to be you.